# How do I move the position of canvas using either css or javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, html5-canvas

this is my first question here. I am fairly new to html, css, and javascript.

What I wanted to achieve was similar to this mockup i've created:
[my website mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uD6M.jpg)

I've tried to replace the rectangle on the left side with javascript code to achieve a similar effect. The javascript code was taken from this codepen:

https://codepen.io/vaaghu/pen/abmYGYz

I've nudged the canvas a bit to the right, but if i extend the canvas width and height, the canvas does extend, but the circle animations don't. How do I extend this animation?

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas")


canvas.width = 800;
canvas.height = 1600;
var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
var mouse = {x:innerWidth/2,y:innerHeight/2}
window.addEventListener("mousemove",(event)=>{
  mouse.x = event.x;
  mouse.y = event.y;
})
window.addEventListener("resize",()=>{
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  int();
})
function Circle(x, y,dx,dy,radius,color) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.dx = dx;
  this.dy = dy;
  this.radius = radius;
  this.color = color
  var maxRadius = 30;
  this.draw = function() {
    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(this.x,this.y,this.radius,0,Math.PI * 2,false);
    c.fillStyle = color
    c.fill();
  }
  this.update = function(){
    if(this.x+this.radius > innerWidth || this.x-this.radius < 0) {
      this.dx = -this.dx;
     }
     if(this.y+this.radius > innerHeight || this.y -this.radius < 0 ) {
       this.dy = -this.dy;
      }
      if( mouse.x - this.x > -50 && mouse.x - this.x < 50 && mouse.y - this.y >-50 && mouse.y - this.y < 50) {
   
        if (this.radius < maxRadius) {
          this.radius += 1
        }

      } else {

        if (this.radius > radius) {
          this.radius -= 1
        }
      }
       
     this.x += this.dx;
     this.y += this.dy;
     this.draw();
  }
  
}
  
 var colorArray = ["#F5871A","#81968F","#DFAA2F","#D76034","#F5411D"];
  var circleArray = []
  function int() {
    circleArray = []
     for (let i = 0; i < 700; i++) {
  var x = Math.random() * window.innerWidth;
  var y = Math.random() * (window.innerHeight ) ;
  var radius = Math.random() * 5 + 2;
  var dx = Math.random() - 0.5;
  var dy = Math.random() - 0.5;
  var color = colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*4)]
  circleArray.push(new Circle(x,y,dx,dy,radius,color))
  }
  }
 int()

  function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    c.clearRect(0,0,innerWidth,innerHeight)
    for (let i = 0; i < circleArray.length; i++) {
    circleArray[i].update()  
    }
    }
animate();
```

```css
.mediaViewInfo {
    --web-view-name: Homepage;
    --web-view-id: Homepage;
    --web-scale-on-resize: true;
    --web-show-navigation-controls: true;
    --web-enable-deep-linking: true;
    --web-page-font: arial, Manrope;
}
:root {
    --web-view-ids: Homepage;
}
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: none;
}
#Homepage {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height:450%;
    font-family: arial, Manrope;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    overflow: hidden;
    --web-view-name: Homepage;
    --web-view-id: Homepage;
    --web-scale-on-resize: true;
    --web-show-navigation-controls: true;
    --web-enable-deep-linking: true;
    --web-page-font: arial;
}
 


canvas {
    background: #FFFF05;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #81968F99, #FFE636CC, #FF000066);
    margin: 50% 0% 0% 8%;
    padding: 0vh 0vh 0vh 0vh;
    z-index:-1;
    width:auto;
    
}
#Wave_Vid {
    position: absolute;
    left: -19px;
    top: -1920px;
    width: 100vh;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.Wave_container {
    overflow: visible;
    
}


#MIDDLEcontainer {
    position:absolute;
    top: 24%;
    left:59%;
}
#MIDDLE { 
    overflow: visible;
}
#Good_ideas_can_take_time {
    line-height: 0.8;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    padding-right: 10%;
    font-family: Manrope, arial;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15vh;
    color: rgba(129,150,143,1);
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#And_execution_takes_even_more {
    width: 100%;
    
    line-height: 1em;
    text-align: left;
    padding-right: 30vh;
    font-family: Manrope, arial;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 5vh;
    color: rgba(129,150,143,1);
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#Line_ {
    fill: transparent;
    stroke: rgba(129,150,143,1);
    stroke-width: 4px;
    stroke-linejoin: miter;
    stroke-linecap: butt;
    stroke-miterlimit: 4;
    shape-rendering: auto;
    
}
.Line_ {
    width: 509px;
    height: 10px;
    transform: matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}


#Midcontainer {
    position:absolute;  
}
#Mid {
  float:bottom;
    position:absolute;
}

.MySkills {
    position: relative;
    overflow:visible;
    height: 1em;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Manrope, arial;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 12vh;
    color: rgba(129,150,143,1);
    letter-spacing: -0.85px;
    
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>wbdg portfolio</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="applicationStylesheet" href="../faux styles.css"/>

</head>
<body>
    
<div>
        <canvas></canvas>   
            <script id="jssomething" type="text/javascript" src="../faux scripts.js"></script>
                <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4f3ce16e3e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>     
    <div id="MIDDLEcontainer">
    <div id="MIDDLE">
        
        <div id="Good_ideas_can_take_time">
            <p>Good ideas can take time.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="And_execution_takes_even_more">
            <span>And execution takes even more.</span>
        </div>
        <svg class="Line_" viewBox="0 0 674 4">
            <path id="Line_" d="M 0 0 L 674 0">
            </path>
        </svg>
        <div id="Midcontainer">
            <div id="Mid">
                <div class="MySkills"> Photos </div>
                <div class="MySkills"> Illustrations </div>
                <div class="MySkills"> Videos </div>
                <div class="MySkills"> Animations </div>
                <div class="MySkills"> Branding </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, change these lines in `int()` function:

```
  var x = Math.random() * window.innerWidth;
  var y = Math.random() * (window.innerHeight ) ;
```

to this:

```
  var x = Math.random() * canvas.width;
  var y = Math.random() * canvas.height;
```

Comment: thank you for the answer! the circle animations have extended, but now this happens :(
https://imgur.com/1eryVR5

the circles expand horizontally and never stop, and hovering the mouse doesn't work.